# Google maps v3 - listen and report authentication errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

According to Google Maps documentation you can listen for authentication errors programatically (see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors).

However, no mention is made of any arguments being passed to the gm_authFailure() function and no mention is made if any global error message or code is available.

Question:

How do we report the specific TYPE of authentication error that occurred as listed at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages given that no information as to what TYPE of error occurred is available in the callback?

Am I missing something obvious? Probably, but please point it out anyway! :) ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like Google Maps JavaScript API calls this function without parameters.

Comment: Exactly my point -- without a parameter indicating the TYPE of authentication error that occurred, you cannot report any real details as to what caused the error !